# Exception while using FullTextSqlQuery in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, full-text-search

We are using Sharepoint 2007 and FullTextSqlQuery in one of our pages.

This is the query we are using:

```
query = "SELECT Title,Path,Write,Rank,Size,Description FROM scope() WHERE  ((\"SCOPE\" = 'Docstudy'))";
```

The above query executes successfully but when I try to select other columns like "Domain", "DocumentType" then below exception occurs =>

> Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings.

We have included `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query,Microsoft.Office.Server.Search` and
`Microsoft.Office.Server` assemblies.

After doing some Google we found that we need to check with managed properties but we are not getting what and how exactly resolve this issue.

What am I missing? Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance,
Rushikesh

Answer (score 1):

You need to map Crawled Properties (found by the indexer) to Managed Properties which are site columns e.g. your "Domain" column. Do this via the SSP Search configuration pages.